# .call/.apply set a Number for this not as a Primitive Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to write a function to repeat a function x times.
Now i want to pass the counter of the repetition as 'this', but the passed value is not a real Number, it's an object containing a 'PrimitiveValue'.

Livedemo: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lda6qnp/

is there a way to set it as a Number?
func.apply( Number(i), args ); doesn't work.

```
repeat = function( count, func ) {
    var args = [];

    $.each( arguments, function( index, value ) {
        if($.isNumeric(value)) {
            args[args.length] = Number(value);
        } else {
            args[args.length] = value;
        }
    });

    args = args.slice( 2 );

    for( var i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        func.apply( i, args );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any good reason to pass a counter as `this`. Just pass it as a parameter instead.

---

The reason why you are seeing `Number` objects is that in sloppy mode all `this` values are converted to objects implicitly. You need to use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for your `func` if you want to avoid that.

```
repeat( 3, function( a1, a2 ) {
    "use strict";
     $('#result').append( this + ' - type: ' + typeof this + '   - arguments: ' + a1 + ' ' + a2 + ' ' + '<br>' );
}, 1, 'Hallo');
```

Comment: Okay, now i'm adding it as the last parameter.
Thank you for the help!

I thought if I have many unused values like
function( useX, useY, useZ, counter) and all the 'use-' values should be undefined it's annoying to list them all and this would be easier, but i think to add it as parameter is the nevertheless best solution.

Comment: @Joriktos: I'd recommend to use it for the first parameter even. The `index` is a quite essential part for the `repeat` callback.